# Rails Console always returning Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, vagrant

After `RAILS_ENV=development rails c`
`rails console development`
etc...

My console cant return any values for my queries. And of course , i have data.
I am using vagrant and port_fowarding.

```
[20] pry(main)> User.first
  Empresa::Empresa Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "empresas".* FROM "empresas" WHERE "empresas"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "usuarios".* FROM "usuarios" INNER JOIN "pessoas" ON "pessoas"."id" = "usuarios"."pessoa_id" AND "pessoas"."empresa_id" IS NULL WHERE (pessoas.empresa_id = NULL)  ORDER BY "usuarios"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

No matter what, always returning Nil.

Comment: if you're using vagrant where is your database?

Comment: try running `rails db` to open up a database client connected to your development db and triple-check that you do indeed have data

Comment: db running at vagrant image?! :D